# Python 3 SSL cannot grab certificate

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, connection-refused

I'm trying to have a simple function collect certificates from servers. Using Python 3.10.8 and my code looks something this:

```
import ssl

def certgrab(dom):
    address = (dom, 443)
    try:
        f = ssl.get_server_certificate(address)
    except Exception as clanger:
        return {'clanger': clanger}
    print(f)
```

This is fine when I try it against 'google.com' or 'microsoft.com'. But most websites return the following error:{'clanger': ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None)}.

I was wondering if it was a rejection because the sites don't like the user-agent (requests works fine with everything I test against, but obviously cannot grab the cert (unless it secretly can - which would be great!). But I cannot find a way of specifying one in the SSL library.

I'm at a bit of a loss as it works against 'google.com' and 'microsoft.com' (but then I suppose they may have set their sites to be generous / forgiving regarding what types of connections they support).

Answer (score 0):

> ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

This has nothing to do with certificates, not even with TLS. This is a connection error at the TCP level, i.e. even before any TLS and certificates are in effect.

> But most websites return the following error ...

If this is really "most websites" then you might have serious problems in your infrastructure which limit access to large parts of the internet. Or, you might need to use a proxy - but ssl.get_server_certificate does not support a proxy.

Comment: Thanks. So what if there *isn't* a serious problem in the infrastructure? Python requests works fine, browsing all the sites works. If *none* of them responded I could understand it. But why does Microsoft and Google both work?

Comment: @voltesque: if Python requests and browser work - do you have a proxy which is needed to access these sites? And do requests and browser really work from exactly the same machine, with the same user account as you use for running the program in your question.

Comment: the last question is the easiest to answer: yes. Same machine, same user account python requests and browsers work fine. First question: yes there is a proxy. So do you think the code is fine, but there is something else causing the issue? Again: it works for Microsoft and Google. But I'll try bypassing the proxy and see if that resolves it. Thank you.

Comment: @voltesque: if there is a proxy in place than it is likely used by the browser and requests, but not by your code. since ssl.get_server_certificate does not support a proxy.

Comment: you were right. I needed to proxy the communication and as ssl.get_server_certificate can't support a proxy that's why it kept failing. I still cannot work out why it resolved (or appeared to resolve) microsoft.com and google.com. Thank you for your advice. I ended up using python_socks.sync.